# I can't add a Hash to a Stash in Catalyst

Tags: perl, catalyst

I have a hash with some key/value pairs

```
my %hash = ('key1','value1', 'key2', 'value2');
```

I pass it in the Stash to use it in a html template:

```
$c->stash( theHash => %hash);
```

And then, in the Template, to display the values I think I should use something like

```
[% theHash.key1 %] #It should display "value1"
[% theHash.key2 %] #It should display "value2"
```

But it does not work.

It works if I pass values one by one:

```
$c->stash( valueOfHash1 => $hash{'key1'});
$c->stash( valueOfHash2 => $hash{'key2'});
```

And retrieving it as

```
[% valueOfHash1 %] #It displays "value1"
[% valueOfHash2 %] #It displays "value2"
```

But the hash will have a lot of values. It does one seems to be a good idea.

What I am missing? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you drop a hash into list context, it gets unrolled into a list.

You want to store a hash reference.

```
$c->stash( theHash => \%hash);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use this approach:

```
$c->stash->{theHash} = { %hash }; # It creates an anonym hash reference 
                                  # which keeps the %hash data
...
print $c->stash->{theHash}->{key1}; # value1
```